# Error al heredar una clase en kotlin

Tags: poo, funciones, kotlin, class

Estoy intentando heredar una clase de acuerdo a como me enseñaron pero me marca error

```
['modelo' hides member of supertype 'transporte' and needs 'override' modifier"]
```

este es mi código teniendo en cuenta que en mi clase transporte tengo mas variables pero estoy probando con una solamente

```
class moto():transporte(){
var modelo: String=""

constructor(modelo:String):this(){
this.modelo = modelo

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código deberia verse asi

```
open class transporte(){
    open var modelo : String = ""
}

class moto():transporte(){
    override var modelo: String=""
    
    constructor(modelo:String):this(){
        this.modelo = modelo
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución , revisar [answer], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Del mismo modo que puedes sobreescribir ("override") un método, puedes extender una clase ("open") en Kotlin.

Por un lado, tienes la clase transporte para extender:

```
open class transporte() {
    open var modelo : String = " " *// si inicializas por defecto, te recomiendo evitar lateinit o lazy*
}
```

Por otro lado, tienes tu clase "moto", que extiende de "transporte". Con ello, la moto tendrá las propiedades del transporte más las propias:

```
class moto() : transporte() {
    override var modelo : String = " Derby " *// aquí sobreescribimos "modelo" con, por ejemplo en este caso, "Derby"*
```

Y por último, tu constructor que es correcto:

```
constructor(modelo : String) : this() {
        this.modelo = modelo
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Aclaraciones**: Primero por **convención** las `class` deben comenzar en mayúscula y las funciones en minúscula. Eso se aplica en Kotlin.

Ejemplo:

```
class Transporte {}
class Moto {}
fun unaFuncion(){}
```

En Kotlin la `class` no necesita paréntesis salvo que queramos pasarle parámetros.
Las funciones siempre llevan paréntesis con o sin parámetros.

#### Creando class en Kotlin

Vamos a crear una `class Transporte` e instanciamos para crear una `moto`. La variable que vamos a usar es solo `modelo`.

Podemos hacer la `class` básica de la siguiente manera:

```
class Transporte{
    var modelo : String = ""

    fun imprimirModelo(){
        this.modelo = "Modelo: " + this.modelo
        println(this.modelo)
    }
    fun asignarModelo(modelo : String){
        this.modelo = modelo
    }
}
```

`var modelo : String = ""` La variable `var modelo` nos permite darle valores de tipo String y modificarlo.

`fun imprimirModelo()` Agregamos una función que nos sirve para imprimir el valor de la variable.

`fun asignarModelo(modelo : String)` Tenemos una función para asignar el modelo actual en la variable modelo de la clase.

#### Creamos instancia Moto de clase Transporte

En este caso consideramos a moto como un Transporte y utiliza los mismo atributos y métodos.

```
    //Creamos `moto` instancia de `Transporte`    
    moto = Transporte()

    // Agignamos modelo a `moto`
    moto.asignarModelo("Yamaha")

    // Imprimimos el modelo cargado de la moto
    moto.imprimirModelo()
```

Muestra de imprimirModelo()

```
Modelo: Yamaha
```

#### Heredando la clase

Micro ahora es una instancia de clase Transporte.

```
class Micro : Transporte{
    var velocidad : Int = 0
    constructor(modelo : String, velocidad : Int): super(modelo){
        this.velocidad = velocidad
    }
}
```

Si queremos construir un objeto de clase `Micro` solo alcanza con:

```
elArgentino = Micro("Mercedez",90)
```

#### Clase con variable como parámetro

Kotlin nos permite crear la clase y proveer los parámetros.

```
class Transporte(var modelo : String){    
    fun imprimirModelo(){
        this.modelo = "Modelo: " + this.modelo
        println(this.modelo)
    }
    fun asignarModelo(modelo : String){
        this.modelo = modelo
    }
}
```

`class Transporte(var modelo : String)` Cuando instanciamos cargamos el String modelo "Yamaha" a la variable.

```
moto = Transporte("Yamaha")
moto.imprimirModelo() // Modelo: Yamaha
```

#### Constructor primario en Kotlin

Hay diferente constructores en Kotlin y podemos utilizarlas con solo hacer una llamada.

**Función solo a modo ejemplo**:

```
// una función que crea un `auto` instancia de `Transporte` y luego le modifica el `modelo`

    fun transportesToyota(){
        var auto = Transporte("Toyota")
        val ventanas : Int = 6
        // ....
        // ....
        // ....
        // cambiamos el modelo del auto por Corolla
        auto.asignarModelo("Corolla")
        
    }
```

**Ultimo**: En el caso de querer utilizar la palabra reservada `constructor` para `class Transporte()`, podemos utilizar el secundario.

```
class Transporte(var modelo : String){    
    var modelo : String = ""

   constructor(modelo : String): this(){
        this.modelo = modelo
    }
```

Espero que estos ejemplos hayan sido útiles.